# UV Mapping (Unwrapping for Image Textures)

Tags: uv

I've done the UV Mapping (Unwrapping for Image Textures) tutorial and I've managed to successfully fill my cube with a layout.

However, my solid is a prism and I'm struggling to do the same with it.

What I did was to fill the dimensions in the transform menu x=1, y=2,4, z=3,51 and then do same steps, but my layout still keeps as cube.

[image]

Can someone help please?

Comment: Have you scaled it in object mode? In that case, go to Object mode and ctrl A > Apply Scale, then unwrap again

Comment: @PedroGordalina when that answer solves your question, it's a custom on Stack Exchange to *accept* it, giving you some bonus reputation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Object mode and ctrl A > Apply Scale, then unwrap again